# Sort columns in a row after numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a task where I need to order the results of query in a way, that the highest of 3 values gets displayed in the first column after the ID, the second highest in the middle one and the smallest in the last column.

The tables look like this:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 30 | 50 | 40 |
| 2345 | 40 | 30 | 60 |
| 3456 | 60 | 50 | 40 |

And the result should look like this:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 50 | 40 | 30 |
| 2345 | 60 | 40 | 30 |
| 3456 | 60 | 50 | 40 |

The values are package dimensions which need to be in order to be processed.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple using `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t outer apply
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3             
      from (select v.col,
                   row_number() over (order by v.col desc) as seqnum
            from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3)
                 ) v(col)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

SQL Server is quite efficient when using `APPLY` within a single row.  I would expect the performance to be comparable to a bunch of complex `case` expressions.  In addition, this gives more flexibility if any of the values are `NULL`.

And, it is much easier to expand to more columns!

Comment: this solution worked perfect :) i replaced the "left join" with "outer apply" in your solution. your solution also handled the problem of ordering several same values in row. thank you @gordon linoff

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple and short way of achieving this.

Try below query:

```
select
    case when col1 > col2 and col1 > col3 then col1
    else case when col2 > col1 and col2 > col3 then col2 
         else col3 end end,
    case when (col1 > col2 and col1 < col3) or (col1 < col2 and col1 > col3) then col1
    else case when (col2 > col1 and col2 < col3) or (col2 < col1 and col2 > col3) then col2
         else col3 end end,
    case when col1 < col2 and col1 < col3 then col1
    else case when col2 < col1 and col2 < col3 then col2
         else col3 end end
from tbl
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/227b8d/5)

Comment: Thank you. I will try the CASE WHEN. I was hoping that there is a function but as long as it does the trick

Comment: @NORiiS If answer has helped you, remember to accept it (green check mark on the left). Optionally, upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may also unpivot it, sort the value and then pivot it back

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT t.id, v.col, 
          col_no = row_number() over (partition by t.id order by v.col desc)
   FROM   yourtable t
          CROSS APPLY
          (
             VALUES (col1), (col2), (col3)
          ) v (col)
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(col)
    for col_no in ([1], [2], [3])
) p
```

Answer (score -2):

the question is not clear but you can use a temp table. First, read the top 3 of data with ordering highest, secondly do it same again with offset value 3, 6 and third times order by lowest.

push the results after each step

read the temp table